# RubyJmeter : listeners configuration?

Tags: ruby, ruby-jmeter

I'm using [ruby-jmeter](https://github.com/flood-io/ruby-jmeter) to perform load tests on my rails API. I wrote a simple test like this :

```
test do
  threads count: 1, loops: 50 do
    transaction name: 'My API' do
      visit name: 'Products', url: "#{BASE_URI}/api/products"
    end
  end

  view_results_tree
  response_time_graph
end.run(path: "#{JMETER_PATH}", gui: true)
```

However the default `response_time_graph` listener generated has a default 10000ms interval, which I would like to set to 1000ms. But I didn't find any information about this in the docs, and it seems like no one tried this before...

I tried to edit the interval with the JMeter GUI and found out that it added this line in the .jmx xml file :

```
<stringProp name="RespTimeGraph.interval">1000</stringProp>
```

But I can't find how to set this from my ruby code. I saw in the source code that the dsl method takes parameters, but I can't find how to set them properly.
See https://github.com/flood-io/ruby-jmeter/blob/master/lib/ruby-jmeter/dsl/response_time_graph.rb

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported as of ruby-jmeter 2.13.7
It will need a pull request to implement it.